# Is there a quick way to decrease the indentation of multiple lines in Python?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, edit, indentation

I am a newbie to python programming. I find that decreasing the indentation of a block of codes in python is quite annoying. For example, given the following code snippet

```
for i in range(density):
   if i < 5:
      x, y = rnd(0,shape[1]//2)*2, rnd(0,shape[0]//2)*2
      Z[y,x] = 1 
      ....
      ....
```

If I comment the `if` statement, I have to decrease the indentation for lines in the if block one by one, is there a way that I can do this by one key stroke as I increase the indentation of a block of codes by selecting them and press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key? I guess this is environment dependent, so could you please provide solutions to do so in Eclipse+Pydev, VIM, and other common editors?

Comment: It would depend editor to editor. You'd have to look into each one specifically.

Comment: In Komodo and Visual Studio you select the lines and press Shift+Tab.

Comment: in this particullar case you could also increase the indent of the commented out "if" line.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In vim, you select the block and then press the <kbd><</kbd> key.

In Eclipse you select it and then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Every code editor worth its salt has a one-key way to indent and dedent blocks.

Comment: Do you need any VIM configure file to make that work? @Borealid

Comment: In IDLE (the IDE included with Python), `CTRL`+`[` dedents and `CTRL`+`]` indents.

Comment: Also `C-c <` for emacs (in python-mode)

Comment: Selecting text then using the shift+tab shortcut also works if you're using the Python editor built into Canopy on Windows.

Comment: Is there any way to configure Eclipse to use something instead of `SHIFT` + `TAB` ? I'd like to make it use `Ctrl` + `[` like Sublime uses...

Answer (score 8):

You could also replace the if statement with:

```
if True:  # if i < 5:
```

and leave everything else alone - no indent/dedent to undo later.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps late for your case, but if useful for others:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> will do unindent for the selected text in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Use Preferences-Pydev-Editor settings uncheck change tabs to spaces. It makes detent errors and your problem. And test other options like 4 space tab, 8 space tab and so on.